# I need to create a Angular directive to clear content entered in input field in icon button click

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I have created a directive which will show clear button icon only if there is any content inside input field. Also I need that on button click input content should get cleared.

As host element is not input itself value is setting to empty inside directive but not getting reflected in the component.

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput  #inputVal type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value" />
    <mat-icon [clearInput]= "inputVal.value" class="suffix" matSuffix >Close</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

Directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clearInput]',
  exportAs: 'clearInput'
})
export class clearInputDirective implements OnChanges{
   
    @Input('clearInput') inputValue: any;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2) {
      
  }
  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.inputValue = null;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    if(changes.inputValue){
   
     if(this.inputValue){
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
       }
       else {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add directive selector in your   `HTML`  ?

Comment: `<input  clearInput  type="text"  class="form-control"  formControlName="Todo" />`

Comment: @Wasim If i add selector inside input , its not showing even initial value

Comment: Are you using form controls ?

Comment: actual implementation of this directive can use form control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem acc. to me is **clearInput** is not bind to your **inputVal** it's just taking a value and acting accordingly in directive.
for your approach to work you need full reference of **inputVal** in directive.

Right now it's just a primitive value that's why when you change the value to null it's only on directive level.

**[EDIT]**

Try below code.  - as you are using ngmodel then we need reference of ngmodel

```
<div class="input">
 <input matInput  clearInput [clearInput]= "value" #inputVal type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value" />
<div class="alwaysCloseButtonWillBethere" 
    matSuffix >Close</div>
</div>
```

clear directive -- just i have taken a constant like html is like **div[input , close]**  when you click on close input will get empty

```
    import { Directive, OnChanges, Input, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2, SimpleChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clearInput]',
  exportAs: 'clearInput'
})
export class ClaerinputDirective implements OnChanges , OnInit , OnDestroy{
   
    @Input('clearInput') inputValue: any;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2 , private model: NgModel) {
      
  }

  ngOnInit(){
     this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1].addEventListener('click', () =>{
       this.model.control.reset();
     })
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
   if(changes.inputValue){
      if(this.inputValue){
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1], 'display', 'block');
       }
       else {
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1], 'display', 'none');
       }
   }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1].removeEventListener('click',null
     );
  }
}
```

---

### if dom node are not static , then use below it based on class name i have taken class name --- alwaysCloseButtonWillBethere

```
     import { Directive, OnChanges, Input, HostListener, ElementRef, Renderer2, SimpleChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clearInput]',
  exportAs: 'clearInput'
})
export class ClaerinputDirective implements OnChanges , OnInit , OnDestroy{
   
    @Input('clearInput') inputValue: any;
    nodeToHideAndShow: HTMLElement;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2 , private model: NgModel) {
      
  }

  getNode(){
   if(!this.nodeToHideAndShow){
     this.nodeToHideAndShow = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.querySelector('.alwaysCloseButtonWillBethere');
    }

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.getNode();
    if(!this.nodeToHideAndShow){
      // alert('Add a class  alwaysCloseButtonWillBethere')
    } else {
      console.log('d');
      this.nodeToHideAndShow.addEventListener('click', () => {
       this.model.control.reset();
     })
    }
     
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
   if(changes.inputValue){
     this.getNode();
      if(this.inputValue){
       this.renderer.setStyle( this.nodeToHideAndShow, 'display', 'block');
       }
       else {
        this.renderer.setStyle( this.nodeToHideAndShow, 'display', 'none');
       }
   }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if( this.nodeToHideAndShow){
          this.nodeToHideAndShow.removeEventListener('click',null);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: After modifying input property to  [val]="inputVal.value" (as after clicking icon was not getting hidden) , Input Field value is not getting updated in component.ts. Its only getting updated in html template.

Comment: i guess as ngmodel is there , then this current implantation will  not work , we need a instance of NgModel in directive to work then

Comment: @sneha i have updated the code please have a check with this implementation

Comment: what if directive user changes dom heirarcy or uses mat form field then using `this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1]` to get alwaysCloseButtonWillBethere will not work.

Comment: Also your first approach is more feasible as I am required to add directive in button. Only there is need to find out way to change input value in model as well

Comment: for that you need to pass a ngModel  to directive , and that can be done too  with some tweeks , but as clearing and ngmodel both are related to input so having a directive for input is better as per my view, will check again  how to modify your current implementation

Comment: @senha this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.children[1]  -- updating code for this one to a class name , just some constants will be check where to add event listner

Comment: @sneha added a class based  approach to find element , if your dom heirarcy  is not fixed. just make sure class name is there, you can even make that class name dynamic with minor changes